# SFMC SQL query to update related records

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

Scenario: I need to update all children from a family based on the values populated from a single child. So if Child A has a city of 'London' for example, I would want Child B and C to have 'London' applied to their city field as well.

Example:

Family/Child:

[image]

Child:

[image]

Final DE:

[image]

In the example above I would want ClientId = 2 and ClientId = 3 to have the value applied to ChildId = 1, since they all have the same familyId. I keep getting twisted in the logic because we need to include a childId in the resulting data extension as it's the primary key, so I don't know how to group the results by familyId and apply to all childIds. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the solution would be to do a subquery that contains value pairs of FamilyId and City. Then you would Join this with your main query matching on FamilyId - so that each entry with that FamilyId will get the adjoining City.

For Example:

```
SELECT  a.ChildID
        , a.FamilyId
        , b.City
FROM [yourDE] a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT  FamilyId
            City
    FROM [yourDE]
    WHERE City IS NOT NULL
    AND City != ''
) b
ON a.FamilyId = b.FamilyId
```

Comment: Do you think adding `WHERE City != NULL` in the subquery be beneficial so that you're *only* getting FamilyId/City pairs that are valid? Also, I'm curious if children in a family can have their own city assignment, so you could have some issues there.

Comment: I think the `WHERE City != NULL` in the sub query is definitely a good idea to ensure only those with matching values are returned.  From what I understood of the OP, The city is based off FamilyId. If this is not the case, then you could insert some `CASE` conditionals to handle if empty then insert `b.City` else insert `a.City`.  But that then runs into some further business rules surrounding cases where FamilyId has more than 1 City, and which one to use, etc.

Comment: It's not entirely consistent in terms of what is empty or not empty, but this example should allow me to fit for all use cases. Just what I needed, thanks!